# PdfKit Annotations Highlight & Save IOS 11

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, pdfkit

Is there any helpful walkthrough on how to use the pdfkit annotations(highlight, comments, etc..) and save the results in swift.

I couldn’t find a helpful one.

Thank you

Comment: Our post "What are Annotations" might be very helpful to understand the basics of the annotation object model here. https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-annotations/

Comment: i want to highlight only hyperlinks in the pdf dcoument, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For Highlight you can use following code :

```
let selections = self.pdfview.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine()
// Simple scenario, assuming your pdf is single-page.
guard let page = selections?.first?.pages.first else { return }

if selections == nil {

}else {

    selections?.forEach({ selection in

        let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
        //            highlight.endLineStyle = .square

        highlight.color = UIColor(red:0.49, green:0.99, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            page.addAnnotation(highlight)
    })
}
```

For Save :

```
self.pdfdocument?.write(to: urlPath!)
```

Comment: The problem is when you save the PDF it can be modified! 
so you can open it via Preview app and you will notice that the PDFAnnotation can be move or delete!